# Understanding Jenkins Groovy scripted pipeline code

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am looking at a Jenkins Scripted Pipeline tutorial here https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/12/02/matrix-building-with-scripted-pipeline/ and found that I need to learn some Groovy to understand this.

I have been reading through Groovy documentation, but still and not understanding all of this code. I will list the areas of question.

### 1

```
List getMatrixAxes(Map matrix_axes) {
List axes = []
matrix_axes.each { axis, values ->
    List axisList = []
    values.each { value ->
        axisList << [(axis): value]
    }
    axes << axisList
}
// calculate cartesian product
axes.combinations()*.sum()
}
```

In most of the Groovy documentation I have seen, it defines lists such as `List axes = []`. The syntax above looks more like a function which would return a List. If this is what this is, I don't see any return statement inside the curly brackets, which just confuses me.

### 2

```
node(nodeLabel) {
            withEnv(axisEnv) {
                stage("Build") {
                    echo nodeLabel
                    sh 'echo Do Build for ${PLATFORM} - ${BROWSER}'
                }
                stage("Test") {
                    echo nodeLabel
                    sh 'echo Do Build for ${PLATFORM} - ${BROWSER}'
                }
            }
        }
```

I have seen this concept of `node` in Groovy scripts before, somethings with the parameter section, ie: `node(nodelabel) {...}` and sometimes without, ie: `node {...}`. Is this core Groovy or somehow something specific to Jenkins? What does it mean and where can I find documentation about it?

Comment: 1.That is not a e.g. method or function so it does not `return` similar to other programming languages. 2. That is Jenkins scripted pipeline DSL.

Comment: @Matt For #1, if its not a method or function, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `getMatrixAxes` is a function. In Groovy return statement is optional. If you don't explicitly return something in a function, the last expression evaluated in the body of a method or a closure is returned. In your case, the output generated by the `axes.combinations()*.sum()` will be returned. In the example, it's generating a `List`. You can read more from [here](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_optional_return_keyword).
2. These constructs are something specific to Jenkins. Specifically the mentioned syntax is from Jenkins Scripted Pipeline Syntax. `node {...}` Simply means run on any agent.  `node(nodelabel) {...}` means run on the agent with the label `nodelabel`. Jenkins has a new Job DSL called Declarative syntax which is preferred over Scripted Syntax. You can read more about both [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/).

Comment: I don't understand your response to #1, the last item in the `getMatrixAxes` function is `axes.combinations()*.sum()`.  If so, THAT would be what is returned by default, making the matrix_axes List not used by anything?... Clearly something I"m missing something here.

Comment: @user1015214 Oops my bad, sorry missed the last line, Yes you are correct. It's the last line that's returned. Updated the answer too. `matrix_axes` is iterated and collected into a List called `axes`.